SVG export is rasterized with certain colors
Bug introduced in 13.2 or earlier and fixed in 14.1
Exporting a mostly-transparent rectangle as SVG gives an expected result:
ExportString[
 Graphics[{RGBColor[0.1, 0, 0], Opacity[0.1], Rectangle[]}], "SVG"]
(* "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" \
xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"360pt\" \
height=\"360pt\" viewBox=\"0 0 360 360\" version=\"1.1\">
<g id=\"surface855\">
<path style=\"fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(10.00061%,0%,0%);fill-\
opacity:0.1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:\
miter;stroke:rgb(10.00061%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:0.1;stroke-\
miterlimit:3.239307;\" d=\"M 7.199219 352.511719 L 7.199219 6.910156 \
L 352.800781 6.910156 L 352.800781 352.511719 Z M 7.199219 352.511719 \
\"/>
</g>
</svg>
" *)

But (in Mathematica 13.2.1.0 on 64-bit Windows 10) changing the color to RGBColor[0.05, 0, 0] gives a rasterized version:
ExportString[
 Graphics[{RGBColor[0.05, 0, 0], Opacity[0.1], Rectangle[]}], "SVG"]
(* "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" \
xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"360pt\" \
height=\"360pt\" viewBox=\"0 0 360 360\" version=\"1.1\">
<defs>
<clipPath id=\"clip1\">
  <path d=\"M 0 0 L 360 0 L 360 359.519531 L 0 359.519531 Z M 0 0 \"/>
</clipPath>
<image id=\"image864\" width=\"1500\" height=\"1498\" \
xlink:href=\"data:image/png;base64,\
iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN […] AAAAElFTkSuQmCC\"/>
</defs>
<g id=\"surface860\">
<g clip-path=\"url(#clip1)\" clip-rule=\"nonzero\">
<use xlink:href=\"#image864\" \
transform=\"matrix(0.24,0,0,0.24,0,-0.096)\"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
" *)

(I've omitted most of the base-64 string.)
Is this a bug or can some colors not be represented in SVG? Is there any way of knowing what colors (or color–transparency combinations) are safe to use?

Most likely a bug.

There is some algorithm that checks this: RGBColor[{r, g, b, o}]; If[Min[{r, g, b}*o] < 6/1000, "raster", "vector"]. So use colors that the least product is at least 6/1000. Then if really needed you can replace the colors inside svg file.

Thanks. I've submitted a report to Wolfram Technical Support, who have confirmed that it's a bug.

A similar problem happening in pure Graphics without any SVG export: Filling opacity affects plot image resolution.
